# Display Category Slug in URL Instead of ID

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-blade

I'm relatively new to Laravel, and I have found myself stuck trying to display category slugs instead of the ID.

```
eg: www.website/.../category-slug
```

My website currently shows  www.website/.../category-id. I have a categories table and a posts table with columns.

```
posts table = | id | title | body | img | post_category_id|

post_categories table = | id | name | catslug |
```

---

**Controller**

```php
public function getPostCategory($id)
{
    $postCategories = PostCategory::with('posts')
        ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
        ->get();

    $posts = Post::orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->where('post_category_id', $id)
        ->paginate(5);

    return view('articles.category.categoriesposts')->withPosts($posts)->with('postCategories', $postCategories);
}
```

---

**Route**

```
Route::get('articles/category/{id}', [ 
    'uses'  =>  'ArticlesController@getPostCategory',
    'as'    =>  'pcategory'
]);
```

I've tried many methods, but nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks,

Ash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ArticlesController.php**

```
public function getPostCategory($slug) {
    $postCategories = PostCategory::with('posts')
                    ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
                    ->where('catslug', '=', $slug)
                    ->first();

    // $postCategories->posts - already is a collection of your posts related only to the category you're looking for

        // return view
        return view ('articles.category.categoriesposts')->with('postCategories', $postCategories);


}

Route::get('articles/category/{slug}',  [ 
     'uses'  =>  'ArticlesController@getPostCategory' ,
     'as'    =>  'pcategory'
] );
```

That's it. Also, you can minify your route code:

```
Route::get('articles/category/{slug}', 'ArticlesController@getPostCategory')->name('pcategory');
```

Comment: i already tried this i get the following error ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Undefined variable: posts (View: /Users/macpro/sites/sixmedia/resources/views/articles/category/categoriesposts.blade.php)

Comment: the problem is that i am trying to loop the posts in by the selected category so i need to access the posts table to loop data and i also need to access the categories table to grab slug for the category

Comment: You don't need to use `$posts` inside your categoriesposts.blade.php. It's enough to use `$postCategories->posts` - that's your collection you can loop through.

`@foreach($postCategories->posts as $post)
    {{ $post->title }}
@endforeach`

Comment: It loads without errors but it does not loop the posts or categories menu..

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
**ROUTE:**

Route::get('articles/category/{slug}',  [ 
'uses'  =>  'ArticlesController@getPostCategory' ,
'as'    =>  'pcategory'
] );
```

---

```
**CONTROLLER**

public function getPostCategory($slug) {
    $postCategories = PostCategory::with('posts')
                    ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
                    ->get();

    $posts = Post::orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->whereHas('post_category', function ($query) use ($slug) {
            $query->where('catslug', 'like', $slug);
        })->paginate(5);

        // return view
        return view ('articles.category.categoriesposts')->withPosts($posts)->with('postCategories', $postCategories);


}
```

Comment: i get the following error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'catslug' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `posts` where `catslug` LIKE drama)

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'catslug' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `posts` where `catslug` LIKE music)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_GET['slug'])){
        $get_slug = $_GET['slug'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE get_slug ='$get_slug'";
        if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $query)){
            $posts = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        }
    }
?>
```

If you wanted to show the result, you may try this code.

```
<?php echo $posts['get-slug']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In `web.app` change `Route::get('articles/category/{id}'...` to `Route::get('articles/category/{category}'`
2. In controller get category parameter in `getPostCategory($category)`
3. Add in category model `getRouteKeyName()` and override id with slug.